# Download plug-ins as defined in the target definition file?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2, target-platform

we've an eclipse RCP application with a target platform where the entire target platform is based on p2 update sites ... The problem is now that we want to use our application in the application domaine for testing purposes (running it in the eclipse environment for debugging), but the problem is that there is no internet connection allowed in this area so we need to download our entire target platform.
Is there a way we can exactly download all plug-ins as defined in the target definition of eclipse?
I know that there is a way of downloading the entire p2 update site, but the problem is that some of this site contains duplicated plug-ins with different versions and because eclipse always uses the latest version we get a lot of conflicts.
That's why we excluded the duplicated plug-ins from our target definition like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The Target definition is only used during build, not at runtime. So I don't understand your question; build the app and run it in the test (no Internet) environment and it won't need to download anything.

Comment: Yes I know it's only used during build, but we don't want to use the built application ... We want to use the eclipse environment because we also have to do some debugging ... Problem is we aren't allowed to bring our own notebook with us so we need to bring the source code and the downloaded target platform ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a Target definition in Eclipse on a workstation with no or limited Internet access, there are (at least) a couple of options:

1. Set up local mirrors of each p2 repository used in your Target. Eclipse p2 has command-line tools to do this. Once you have local mirrors you can create an alternate Target definition that replaces the source repository URLs with the local mirror URLs. The process is [described in more detail here](https://www.bsiag.com/scout/local-p2-mirrors-to-work-offline/).
2. Create an Update Site project that includes all the bundles used in your Target definition. You first create a Feature project that includes everything used in your Target, as well as your workspace projects that make up your plugin(s) or application. You then create an Update Site project that publishes that Feature, and export that Update Site. Exporting will produce a local update site that you can then use in a modified version of your Target definition. Detailed documentation is [here](http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/provisioning-your-target-platform-as-local-p2-site/).

Comment: Thanks the second option sounds exactly like what we're looking for ;) We always wanted to make our target platform offline available so we don't depend on the software update sites anymore ... It's always annoying especially when they suddenly are replaced by newer versions ...

Comment: There is a drawback to option 2: updating your Target Platform means manually updating the Feature and re-exporting the Update Site project. I think the ps commands for mirroring, as described as option 1, would be slightly easier to maintain as the Target Platform changes. To mitigate that, some companies maintain an internal repository that mirrors or proxies public repositories, using a product like Artifactory or Nexus.